# Python logs when redirected to a file appear late

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple Python test code as under:

**tmp.py**

```
import time

while True:
    print "New val"
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I run it as below, I see the logs on terminal normally:

```
python tmp.py
```

But if I redirect the logs to a log file, it takes quite a while before the logs appear in the file:

```
python tmp.py >/tmp/logs.log 2>&1
```

If I do a `cat /tmp/logs.log`, the output appears in that file quite late, or only when I quit the python application by pressing `Ctrl+C`

Why do I not see the logs instantly in the redirected file?

**Is it solvable by simple i/o redirection as I tried? (without doing code changes inside my Python code, by using modules like logging)**

Comment: Try to use "-u" option (python -u tmp.py >/tmp/logs.log 2>&1)

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 2):

The best option for your case is to set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`.

This is a little more robust than calling `#/usr/bin/python -u`, as this may not work in some virtual envs.

In your terminal:

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
python tmp.py >/tmp/logs.log 2>&1 #or however else you want to call your script.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the output is buffered, that means python saves the output in a buffer and flushes it every now and then, but not necessarily after each print.

You could fix by forcing a flush after each print by explicitly calling `sys.stdout.flush()`.

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print "New val"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Since my code is long. It's a lot of work adding a lot of flushes.. Had mentioned "without changes inside Python code" for that reason. Appreciate your response..